# Go: parsing variative YAML

Tags: go, yaml

I want to unmarshall map, which can contain different values, how can I do it in Go with `yaml.v2`?

Currently, I have the following node description:

```
package executors

type OptionMap map[string][]string

type Step struct {
    Exec string
    Pwd  string
    Opts OptionMap
}
```

Sample YAML is the following:

```
steps:
   - exec: maven
     pwd: /code
     opts:
       goals:
         - clean
         - install
       mvn_home: /maven
```

Obviously, node will be unmarshaled if only `goals`, but not `mvn_home` will present there. Is there any way to write the single description for such node?

If no, is there any way to read some part of YAML (under some key) as a plain string or, better, such sort of map as `map[string]OBJECT` and unmarshal that `OBJECT` separately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `map[string]interface{}` to unmarshal. With `interface{}` you can unmarshal it later when required.